# Git and Amazon EC2 public key denied

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, permissions

I had git working before on /var/html/projectfolder and realized it was a security risk so I made a new folder /projects from the root folder and tried to replicate what I did and now it doesnt work.

Here is the backlog of what I did for my local machine and EC2 - server

*Server-EC2*
1.I added my public key to the authorized_user file in ~/.ssh folder
2.Create a bare repository

```
git init --bare
```

3.Change folder permissions to

```
sudo chgrp -R ec2-user *
sudo chmod -R g+ws *
```

**Local Machine**

1. create a local repository with git init
2. touch, add, commit readme file
3. pointed origin master to ec2 via

   git remote add origin ssh://ec2-user@remote-ip/path/to/folder

**This is my output:**

```
Permission Denied (publickey)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to see what going on is to do a

```
 ssh -Tvvv  ssh://ec2-user@remote-ip/path/to/folder
```

Everything matter: the exact case of the path, or the user exact name.
But also the [permission of the `~/.ssh` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470680/gitosis-post-receive-hook-to-deploy-repository-getting-public-key-errors/5471139#5471139) (in which case, have a look at the `sshd` logs on the server, when you are doing your ssh command from the client, which might not be possible here for an `amazon-ec2` server).

See also for illustration "[Creating SSH keys for Gerrit and Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712443/creating-ssh-keys-for-gerrit-and-hudson/3712619#3712619)".

Comment: I get this 

debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tam/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/tam/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tam/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/tam/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tam/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/tam/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: @MrNart are you sure you did copy the content of the public `id_rsa.pub` key correctly to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server: the usual issue is copying it in multiple lines instead of *one* line.

Comment: VonC, I had git working on a diff folder /var/www/html/project but I realized that the folder was a security risk so I deleted the folder. I then made a new folder with a /projects/ path from home and now its not working when I try to push.

Comment: @MrNart make also sure **every parent directory up to your `~/.ssh` is not writable for group `----w----` or others `-------w-`**. Otherwise, are you talking about the folder on the server side? In which case, it could be a path (case) issue.

Comment: I followed and made sure of what you said also it is server side and I've made sure the case is correct.

Comment: @MrNart `path\to\folder` is it the full path from '/' (root) to `xxx.git` (the folder of your bare repo)? To add to the other (now deleted) answer, scp syntax isn't always recommended (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366718/git-clone-requires-ssh-protocol-when-perhaps-it-shouldnt) and the ssh-uri syntax (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9835653/6309) is also good. So your syntax shouldn't be an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

ok so with a little bit of tinkering around, I just instead of pushing I just did a clone of the repository..after I cloned the bare repository and pulled..it seemed to work. Thanks again for the help guys.

Comment: What is the remote address you ended up getting after your clone? What '`git remote -v`' shows in your local clone?